Using a Shortcode or Global Variable in Elementor and Crocoblock Woo Page Builder
I have the following code in my WordPress theme's functions.php file:
// Variable for structure name
$structure_name = "P4O10";

// Shortcode function
function show_structure_name($atts) {
    global $structure_name;
    return $structure_name;
}

// Register shortcode
add_shortcode('STRUCTURE', 'show_structure_name');

This code defines a variable $structure_name and creates a shortcode [STRUCTURE] that outputs the value of $structure_name.
In Elementor's Text Editor, I can use [STRUCTURE], and it correctly displays "P4O10". However, when using the Crocoblock Woo Page Builder, [STRUCTURE] does not get replaced, and the shortcode remains as-is.
Since the structure name (currently "P4O10") changes every month, I don't want to manually update it in every subpage that uses it.
My questions are:

Is there a way to make the [STRUCTURE] shortcode work with the Crocoblock Woo Page Builder?

Alternatively, is there a better solution, like using a global variable that can be accessed in both Elementor and Woo Page Builder, without needing to use a shortcode?


I would appreciate any suggestions or solutions to this problem. Thank you!

We have replicated the issue and haven't faced with any issue
Everything works well with JetWooBuilder
https://prnt.sc/urGM86YT_rwx https://prnt.sc/Gm2JvdX6YBiD Kindly tell us exact steps for recreating the issue Also, a recommendation could be not to use the global variable as it might cause issues
It's better to save the value in options, as an example

Wait. You’ve replicated the issue and everything works, but you also need the exact steps for recreating the issue? I assume you meant you HAVEN’T replicated the issue? Or you’ve replicated the code, but can’t replicate the issue?

@VictoriaBormotova sorry I didn't see the comment, I wrote in the post, that you need to use the "Text Editor" widget, to see the error, not the shortcode widget. Because I use the shortcode as inline text like "Here is the product [STRUCTURE]"
